# Windows Password Regular Expression

Tags: .net, regex, passwords

I am trying to do a regular expression using .NET for a password that enforces the Windows password policy requirements:

1) Is at least 8 characters in length

2) Contains characters from 3 of the following 4 categories:

- English upper case characters (A..Z)
- English lower case characters (a..z)
- Base 10 digits (0..9)
- Special Characters

I tricky part is that from the section above I only need 3 not 4 rules. Does anyone know how can I archive that? My reg exp is below;

```
    ^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).*$
```

Comment: The '3 out of 4' factor is going to end any hope of doing this (at least gratefully) in one REGEXP.

Comment: I think i will take your suggestion and do it through code directly without using regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using just plain VB.Net

Code below;

```
 Public Function IsPasswordInCorrectFormat(ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnLowerLetter, blnUpperLetter, blnDigit, blnSpecials As New Boolean
    Dim intCorrectSet As New Short

    If Password.Length >= 8 Then
        For Each chrLetter In Password.ToCharArray
            If Not blnLowerLetter AndAlso Char.IsLower(chrLetter) Then blnLowerLetter = True : intCorrectSet += 1
            If Not blnUpperLetter AndAlso Char.IsUpper(chrLetter) Then blnUpperLetter = True : intCorrectSet += 1
            If Not blnDigit AndAlso Char.IsDigit(chrLetter) Then blnDigit = True : intCorrectSet += 1
            If Not blnSpecials AndAlso (Char.IsSymbol(chrLetter) OrElse Char.IsSeparator(chrLetter) OrElse _
                                      Char.IsWhiteSpace(chrLetter) OrElse Char.IsPunctuation(chrLetter)) Then blnSpecials = True : intCorrectSet += 1

            If intCorrectSet >= 3 Then Exit For
        Next
    End If

    Return intCorrectSet >= 3
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd set up all four rules using separate regular expressions, and then in code, I'd check for three out of four matches.

Simple, easy-to-read, even for someone that's iffy with regular expressions.  (Not all developers are good with them.  Make it easy on the poor maintenance developer.)

It'll also simplify things if one of the rules changes.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it something like this. "Programming by intent". It's easier to understand than the equivalent regex. Simpler. Likely faster, too — just one pass through the string, no backtracking.

If you want, too, this approach makes it easy to define validity has having characters from a minimum number of the character classes you're looking at...say at least 3 of the 5.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determine password validity
/// </summary>
/// <param name="password"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool IsPasswordValid(string password)
{
    if ( password == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException() ;

    const int MIN                     =  8    ;
    const int MAX                     = 32    ;
    bool      meetsLengthRequirements = password.Length >= MIN && password.Length <= MAX ;
    bool      hasLeadingWhitespace    = char.IsWhiteSpace( password[0]                     ) ;
    bool      hasTrailingWhitespace   = char.IsWhiteSpace( password[ password.Length - 1 ] ) ;
    bool      hasUpperCaseLetter      = false ;
    bool      hasLowerCaseLetter      = false ;
    bool      hasNumericChar          = false ;
    bool      hasSpecials             = false ;
    bool      hasWhitespace           = false ;

    for (int i = 0; i < password.Length; ++i)
    {
        char ch = password[i];

        hasUpperCaseLetter =  char.IsUpper(       ch ) ;
        hasLowerCaseLetter =  char.IsLower(       ch ) ;
        hasNumericChar     =  char.IsDigit(       ch ) ;
        hasWhitespace      =  char.IsWhitespace(  ch ) ;
        hasSpecials        =  char.IsPunctuation( ch )
                           || char.IsSeparator(   ch )
                           || char.IsSymbol(      ch )
                           ;

    }

    bool isValid = !hasLeadingWhitespace
                && !hasTrailingWhitespace
                && hasUpperCaseLetter
                && hasLowerCaseLetter
                && hasNumericChar
                && ( hasSpecials || hasWhitespace )
                ;
    return isValid ;
}
```